# fetch request not sending cookies to PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I am having a weird problem where when I make a fetch request from the client in development it is not sending the cookies to my server (legacy server that does not run on localhost).

Here is my code for the fetch request:

```
get( url ) {
    return fetch(`${API_URL}${url}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: headers(),
      credentials: 'include'
    }).then( parseResponse );
  },
```

Headers is a function that returns the following object:

```
{
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'mobile': 'false'
  }
```

Here are the CORS headers I have set on the server (Access-Control-Allow-Origin is dynamic because fetch has issues with `*`)

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: mobile, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
```

If I print out `$_COOKIE` I get back an empty array and when I look at the request I get `Provisional headers are shown` with no cookies.

Any ideas where I messed up?

Thanks In Advance :-)

Comment: First place I'd look is the browser Network tab in the developer tools.

Comment: Also: is it possible that your cookies are https-only?

Comment: I looked in the network tab and no cookies are sent. And the cookies in the application tab are not set to HTTPS only.

Comment: And these cookies are for the target server domain?

Comment: They are stored as for the local domain (localhost, the server is at x.local) could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes; an HTTP request to domain x.y.z only includes cookies for that domain, not from the origin domain. That's good, because otherwise Facebook would get all the cookies from every site with a little "f" button (and etc).

Comment: Outch, I can't set cookies for x.local from localhost :-(.

Oh well, I wrote a small function to extract the same credentials from a header so it should be fine in development. ( In production they are on the same domain. I tested this and the cookies where sent over just fine ;-) ).

I guess this is my just deserts from not having the server run on localhost ;-)

Thanks a ton for your help!!